# cakephp how can I have data modified by beforeValidate stay modified if validation fails

Tags: cakephp, validation

I have a field that I modify before validation, by removing spaces and uppercasing all letters, like so.

```
    function beforeValidate(){
    $this->data['Oligo']['sequence'] = str_replace(' ', '', $this->data['Oligo']['sequence']);
    $this->data['Oligo']['sequence'] = strtoupper($this->data['Oligo']['sequence']);
}
```

If validation fails, the form is displayed with the original data, not the modified one. Why's that?

I would like the form to have the modified data instead. Do I have to do that in the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you're seeing happens because, in `beforeValidate`, you're modifying values in the `Model::data` member, whereas what gets rendered in your form is in the `Controller::data` member, and `Model::data` never gets sent back to the controller.

What you'll need to do is perform your data massage from the controller. For example, you could refactor the operations performed in `beforeValidate` into a public method `massageData`, which you call before in the controller before the save/validation phase.

In your model:

```
class Oligo extends AppModel
{
  // stuff

  function massageData($data){
    $data['Oligo']['sequence'] = str_replace(' ', '', $data['Oligo']['sequence']);
    $data['Oligo']['sequence'] = strtoupper($data['Oligo']['sequence']);

    return $data;
  }

  // other stuff
}
```

In your controller:

```
class OligosController extends AppController
{
  // stuff

  function add()
  {
    if ($this->data) {
      $this->data = $this->Oligo->massageData($this->data);

      if ($this->Oligo->save($this->data)) {
        // post-save logic
      } else {
        // error handling
      }
    }
    // view context preparation
  }

  // other stuff
}
```

HTH.